# jQuery animate problems - dynamically choose direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using jQuery to move a letter around on a black background. No purpose to this, really just messing around. I have four buttons, left, right, up and down which are supposed to move the letter respectively. But for some reason I'm having problems with the .animate() method. I know I could use a switch statement, but I'm going for a more concise solution.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>O</p>
</div>

<div class="slider-nav">
    <button data-dir="left">Left</button>
    <button data-dir="right">Right</button>
    <button data-dir="top">Up</button>
    <button data-dir="bottom">Down</button>
</div>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
(function($) {

var object = $('p');

$('button').on('click', function() {
    var direction = $(this).data('dir');
    move(direction);
});

function move(dir) {
    var dir = 'margin' + '-' + dir;
    object.animate({dir: '+=25px'}, 500);
};

})(jQuery);
```

Would appreciate help finding the problem with my code. Thanks

Comment: First - margin properties should be camel-cased -> marginLeft,marginRight... and, second, bigger problem: if you check generated HTML in console, you will see that <p> gets dir property...so, you can't put string you've made as param for animate() function. Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039646/how-to-pass-variable-into-jquery-animate-function-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation for dynamic keys in your object literal that you pass to animate.  Also, I was playing around with your idea, and it looks like you still need to do some branching logic to handle right/down if you are adjusting top/left css properties (or margin-top/left).

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/D2RLR/7010/

```
var $o = $('p');
var options = {
    "left":0,
    "top":0
};

//...

function move(dir,oper) {
    if (oper === 'add') {
      options[dir] += 25;
    }
    else {
      options[dir] -= 25;
    }

  $o.animate(options,500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use string as key in object. You could possibly do it through eval function, but i don't recommend it. I would to it like this:

```
function move(dir) {
    var distance = 25,
        dir = 'margin' + '-' + dir,
        animation = {},
        previousValue = parseInt($element.css(dir), 10);

    animation[dir] = previousValue + 25;
    $element.animate(animation, 500);
};
```

And here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6o28x8bt/

Also this will animate just margins,  if you want animate the element to direction as you click the button you will need to do increment/decrement left and right position or margin. Like example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jwL1e558/1/

Hope this will help :)